# How to setup a jboss seam build with Maven that includes downloading and configuring the server?

Tags: java, maven-2, jboss, jakarta-ee, seam

I have a jboss(5.1.0.GA)/seam(2.2.0.GA) app that gives me a lot of work everytime I need to setup a development environment for it.

What I want is to port the build to maven, and have it setup all the development environment for me(including downloading and configuring the AS).

How could I acomplish something like that? Currently the build is managed by eclipse and has a default java ee project structure(projects for ear, ejb and jsf) so a simple example of porting an eclipse java ee project to maven with the above requeriments will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these two posts which can explain how you can use seam-gen and convert it to use maven.

This might be helpful for you.

[Post 1](http://minibiti.blogspot.com/2010/03/seam-20-and-maven.html) and [Post 2](http://minibiti.blogspot.com/2010/03/seamgen-to-maven.html)